# Filter data with subquery in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get some data from Wikidata. I've got a simple query which fetches information about universities:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?site WHERE {
  ?item (p:P31/ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q38723;
    wdt:P17 ?country;
    wdt:P856 ?site.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ru,en". }
}
```

And another query, which gets list of members of the CIS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?state WHERE {
  ?state wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q3624078;
         p:P463 ?memberOfStatement.
  ?memberOfStatement a wikibase:BestRank;
                     ps:P463 wd:Q7779
  MINUS { ?memberOfStatement pq:P582 ?endTime. }
  MINUS { ?state wdt:P576|wdt:P582 ?end. }
}
```

Both work fine. But now I want to combine them to get list of universities which are located in the CIS.  I try to do it like shown in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650840/use-another-sparql-inside-sparql-in-clause) question:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?site WHERE {
  ?item (p:P31/ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q38723;
    wdt:P17 ?country;
    wdt:P856 ?site.
  FILTER(EXISTS {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?state WHERE {
      {
        ?state (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q3624078;
          p:P463 ?memberOfStatement.
        ?memberOfStatement rdf:type wikibase:BestRank;
          ps:P463 wd:Q7779.
        MINUS { ?memberOfStatement pq:P582 ?endTime. }
        MINUS { ?state (wdt:P576|wdt:P582) ?end. }
      }
      FILTER(?country = ?state)
    }
  })
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ru,en". }
}
```

But, for some reason, I get zero results. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I had an idea that `?state` could be some kind of set, but `FILTER(?country IN ?state)` doesn't even run. SPARQL is so confusing :c

Comment: Why not use a subquery: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?site WHERE {
  ?item (p:P31/ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q38723;
    wdt:P17 ?state;
    wdt:P856 ?site.  
  {
  SELECT DISTINCT ?state WHERE {
      ?state (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q3624078;
        p:P463 ?memberOfStatement.
        ?memberOfStatement rdf:type wikibase:BestRank;
          ps:P463 wd:Q7779.
        MINUS { ?memberOfStatement pq:P582 ?endTime. }
        MINUS { ?state (wdt:P576|wdt:P582) ?end. }
      hint:SubQuery hint:runOnce true     
    }
  } SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ru,en". }
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser I didn't know I could do something like this, but it looks like an elegant solution. Thanks! Can you post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: I guess your `FILTER EXISTS` approach also works. Just reuse the variable name: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?site WHERE {
  ?item (p:P31/ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q38723 ; 
    wdt:P17 ?state;
    wdt:P856 ?site.
  FILTER EXISTS {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?state WHERE {
      {
?state (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q3624078;
p:P463 ?memberOfStatement.
 ?memberOfStatement rdf:type wikibase:BestRank;
 ps:P463 wd:Q7779.
MINUS { ?memberOfStatement pq:P582 ?endTime. }
MINUS { ?state (wdt:P576|wdt:P582) ?end. }  
}
 }
  }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ru,en". }
}
`